# ASP.NET - Multiple Web applications - Sharing cache objects

Tags: asp.net, .net, caching, redis, memcached

I'm working on asp.net 4 web project , The project is build with 3 sub projects:

- Site.Admin - Admin Website  - ASP.NET Project
- Site.Core - DB & BL - C# Library
- Site.Web - Frontend Website. - ASP.NET Project

The project is hosted on a **Single windows server 32 bit**

I'm currently using ASP.NET Cache (HttpRuntime.Cache) to cache objects but the problem is that i cant share the cache between Frontend & Admin Websites.

From reading StackOverflow and other posts , i understand that the following options exist:

1. Memcached - No stable windows version ?
2. Couchbase - No free version ? overkill to replace asp.net cache ?
3. AppFabric
4. Redis - No stable windows version?

I'm looking for a free/non paid solution to replace asp.net cache.

I'd like to get some input regarding :

1. Windows install compatibility
2. Performance
3. Ease of use (replacing existing cache code) & .NET API.
4. Other alternatives ?

Comment: Just so you know Couchbase has a community edition that you can use and there are no limitation on cluster size.

Answer (score 3):

I've come across this same problem and we went with AppFabric. We needed to share caching between two web apps, on the same server.

AppFabric is pretty easy to install on a Windows machine and it's easy enough to replace calls to the runtime caching with calls to AppFabric. It is however **very important** that you decide *how* you're planning on using this cache, or, how many times.

In a project for a client we needed to build in an extra app next to a legacy app not knowing how many times this legacy app addressed the runtime cache. Apparently, and this only became apparent *after* switching to AppFabric, the cache was not properly used at all. And now this became painfully obvious, since calls to AppFabric are that much slower than putting objects in the runtime cache (AppFabric uses WCF to communicate with the web apps, where runtime caching directly puts objects in memory). AppFabric isn't slow, but it's significantly slower than runtime caching, so use wisely.

But this legacy app made *thousands of calls* to the cache (yeah, I know). So just run a couple of tests whether this will work for your situation.

Comment: that's exactly what I've read about AppFabric , its a big creature & is alot slower then asp.net cache. My application is also an existing app and heavily uses the cache , any idea if memcached performance better like asp.net cache ?

Comment: @sharru I don't have any experience with MemCached.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you can create a web api service as repository for your cached object.

The solution in simple and using generics you can use the cache for diffent object type.

Some step to follows once che web.api is created.

1) create the connection string to your redis server

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "Redis": "127.0.0.1:6379"
}
```

2) modify the startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // add redis cache service
   services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options => {
   options.Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis");
   options.InstanceName = "User_";
   });

   services.AddSession();
   services.AddMvc();
}
```

3) create a class to interact with your cache instance

```
namespace CacheRepository
{
// declare the class
public static class RedisCache
{

// save 
public static async Task SetObjectAsync<T>(IDistributedCache cache, string key, T value)
{
await cache.SetStringAsync(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
}

// get
public static async Task<T> GetObjectAsync<T>(IDistributedCache cache, string key)
{
var value = await cache.GetStringAsync(key);
return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
}

// verify if an object exists
public static async Task<bool> ExistObjectAsync<T>(IDistributedCache cache, string key)
{
var value = await cache.GetStringAsync(key);
return value == null ? false : true;
}
}
}
```

4) create the controller that expose the public method with the relative http verbs

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet("{name}")]
public async Task<User> GetUser(string name)
{
  User user = new User();
  try
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
     user = await RedisCache.GetObjectAsync<User>(_Cache, name);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
  return user;
}
```

this is a simple way ;)

here below you can find the article in which I describe every detail.

https://medium.com/@massimomannoni/code-web-api-with-redis-distributed-cache-6598dbe854d5

thanks Massimo